# Control speed and changing the color of the ball

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create one website for monitoring kind of thing. Here i need to control the speed of the ball. How to do that?
Then i need to change the color of the balls to red if it collide or overlay with other. If not, it should remain green . I have no idea how to do these thing. Can anyone please help with this?

```js
function getBall(xVal, yVal, dxVal, dyVal, rVal, colorVal) {
  var ball = {
    x: xVal,
    lastX: xVal,
    y: yVal,
    lastY: yVal,
    dx: dxVal,
    dy: dyVal,
    r: rVal,
    color: colorVal,
    normX: 0,
    normY: 0,
    durationAverage: 0,
    durationMin: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    durationMax: 0,
    bounceCount: 0
  };
  return ball;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var containerR = 200;
canvas.width = containerR * 2;
canvas.height = containerR * 2;
canvas.style["border-radius"] = containerR + "px";

var balls = [
  getBall(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - 30, 2, -2, 8, "#32CD32"),
  getBall(canvas.width / 3, canvas.height - 50, 3, -3, 8, "#32CD32"),
  getBall(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height - 60, -3, 4, 8, "#32CD32"),
  getBall(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 5, -1.5, 3, 8, "#32CD32")
];

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    var curBall = balls[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(curBall.x, curBall.y, curBall.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = curBall.color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    curBall.lastX = curBall.x;
    curBall.lastY = curBall.y;
    curBall.x += curBall.dx;
    curBall.y += curBall.dy;
    var dx = curBall.x - containerR;
    var dy = curBall.y - containerR;
    if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - curBall.r) {

      var start = performance.now();

      // current speed
      var v = Math.sqrt(curBall.dx * curBall.dx + curBall.dy * curBall.dy);
      // Angle from center of large circle to center of small circle,
      // which is the same as angle from center of large cercle
      // to the collision point
      var angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
      // Angle of the current movement
      var oldAngle = Math.atan2(-curBall.dy, curBall.dx);
      // New angle
      var newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
      // new x/y speeds, using current speed and new angle
      curBall.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
      curBall.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);

      var end = performance.now();
      var curDuration = end - start;
      curBall.bounceCount++;
      curBall.durationAverage = (((curBall.bounceCount - 1) * curBall.durationAverage) + curDuration) / curBall.bounceCount;
      if (curDuration < curBall.durationMin) {
        curBall.durationMin = curDuration
      }
      if (curDuration > curBall.durationMax) {
        curBall.durationMax = curDuration
      }
    }
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would recommend [p5.js](https://p5js.org) for what you want to do

Comment: I have an answer I can post, but I just want to make sure I am interpreting the question properly: You have two green circles and when they overlap, you want them to turn red. You want to know how to approach this problem.

Comment: @applemonkey496 Thanks for that...Let me put it in better way If any of the green balls meets or collide they should turn red and when they are apart it should turn to green again...this is what i want

Comment: Can you detail what you mean by: `any of the green balls meets` like 5px gap from each other?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda if one ball touches or crosses on another it should turn red otherwise it should remain green. i think this will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for:

```js
function getBall(xVal, yVal, dxVal, dyVal, rVal, colorVal) {
  var ball = {x: xVal, y: yVal, dx: dxVal, dy: dyVal, r: rVal, color: colorVal
  };
  return ball;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8

var containerR = 100;
canvas.width = canvas.height = containerR * 2;

var balls = [
  getBall(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - 30, 1, -0.5, 18, "#32CD32"),
  getBall(canvas.width / 3, canvas.height - 50, 1.2, -1, 15, "#32CD32"),
  getBall(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height - 60, -1.6, 1, 12, "#32CD32"),
  getBall(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 5, -1.5, 1, 8, "#32CD32")
];

function drawBall(curBall) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(curBall.x, curBall.y, curBall.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = curBall.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function updateBallPos(curBall) {
  curBall.x += curBall.dx;
  curBall.y += curBall.dy;
  var dx = curBall.x - containerR;
  var dy = curBall.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - curBall.r) {
    var v = Math.sqrt(curBall.dx * curBall.dx + curBall.dy * curBall.dy);

    var angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    var oldAngle = Math.atan2(-curBall.dy, curBall.dx);

    var newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    curBall.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    curBall.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}

function ballsMeet(b1, b2) {
  return (Math.hypot(Math.abs(b1.x - b2.x), Math.abs(b1.y - b2.y)) < (b1.r + b2.r))
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    drawBall(balls[i])
    updateBallPos(balls[i])

    meet = false
    for (var j = 0; j < balls.length; j++) {
      if (ballsMeet(balls[i], balls[j]) && i != j) {
        meet = true
        balls[j].color = "red"
      }
    }
    balls[i].color = (meet) ? "red" : "lime"
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
```

I significantly stripped your code just to focus on the color change, the balls had a lot of properties that my guess you will use later for something else but not really relevant for the issue you are having at the moment.

Also I split your code into multiple smaller functions easier to read that way.

So the idea is to check every ball against all others see if they "meet" and if they do we change the color, I slow down the speed of your example to smooth the animation a little if not I was getting a lot of change from red to green this was it shows what is happening

Comment: Yes It works..How to change the speed of the balls?

Comment: @Anonymous the speed of the balls is what you coded as `dxVal, dyVal` ... how do you call that?

Answer (score -1):

You can calculate the Euclidean distance between the two circles' centres. If it is less than the sum of the radii of the two circles, they are overlapping.

```js
let euclideanDistance = Math.hypot(Math.abs(x1-x2), Math.abs(y1-y2));
let sumOfRadii = circle1radius + circle2radius;

if (euclideanDistance <= sumOfRadii) {
  makeCirclesRed();
} else if (euclideanDistance > sumofRadii) {
  makeCirclesGreen();
}
```

**Explanation:**

`Math.hypot()` calculates the hypotenuse of a triangle given the two leg legnths, which happens to be the same as the formula for Euclidean distance

`Math.abs()` just makes sure that the input to the `hypot()` function is positive. It *might* not actually be necessary, so you can try experimenting without it.

You can fill in the `makeCirclesRed()` and `makeCirclesGreen()` functions to suit your needs.

**Edit:** if you want to make the circles red if they meet *or* come within `x` pixels of each other, you can change `sumOfRadii = circle1radius + circle2radius + x` for your desired value of `x`.

Comment: As is this code will eventually turn all balls red... I guess you are missing an else `meets or collide they should turn red and when they are apart it should turn to green again`

Comment: @applemonkey496 can you be more specific to my code like..can you add snippet